# Simulink: Add controls to simulink mask tab programatically

Tags: matlab, tabs, simulink, mask

I am trying to add a parameter to a mask tab, using m-code.
Let's say I want to add an 'edit' parameter, and a 'popup' parameter.

So far, I cannot get to put them in the tab, they stay in the general group. The mathworks documentation is failing to provide working guidelines:

- The addDialogControl method is failing for everything else than 'text' and 'hyperlink' items
- The 'TabName' parameter issue a warning (going to be removed, not allowed to use). The warning says "Use tab dialog controls to add parameters to tabs ". There's no documentation about this, nowhere.
- The example they provide is incomplete and goes not give the displayed result (parameters stay out of the tab), see this link: https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/control-masks-programmatically.html#bu47973-4

I noticed that there's a Simulink.dialog.Control class which have a 'moveTo' method, but parameters are not Simulink.dialog.Control, they are Simulink.MaskParameter instance. There is also a Simulink.dialog.parameter.Control class but I do not know which objects actually belong to it nor if it could help me.

Thanks for helping, I just need a minimal example to show me how to do this.

Comment: If possible, you are often better designing the dialog to have all expected controls on it at the start, and then just toggling the 'Visible' property when you need/don't need a particular control.

Comment: This is what we will do because ouf mask does not need to be dynamic anyway (we just need several different masks for the same interface class). However I found a solution

Answer (score 0):

Here is the good way to do it: using the 'moveTo' method I spoke above.

To access the parameter Simulink.dialog.parameter (which contains the moveTo method) from the Simulink.MaskParameter you just create, you need to use the getDialogControl on the Maskparameter

Convoluted and complex ? Yes, but that's what you have to do.

Here is a MWE:

```
block = 'Untitled1/Atomic Subsystem';

wMask = Simulink.Mask.get(block);

if ~isempty(wMask)
    wMask.delete();
end

wMask = Simulink.Mask.create(block);

wMask.addDialogControl('tabcontainer','tabContainer');

wTabContainer = wMask.getDialogControl('tabContainer');

wTab1 = wTabContainer.addDialogControl('tab', 'Tab1');
wTab2 = wTabContainer.addDialogControl('tab', 'Tab2');

wTab1.Prompt = 'Programatically added tab1';
wTab2.Prompt = 'Programatically added tab2';

wTextOnFirst            = wTab1.addDialogControl('text', 'textOnFirst');
wTextOnFirst.Prompt     = 'Some text on the first tab';
wTextOnSecond           = wTab2.addDialogControl('text', 'textOnSecond');
wTextOnSecond.Prompt    = 'Some text on the first tab';

wField = wMask.addParameter('Name', 'TextField' ...
    , 'Type', 'edit'...
    , 'Prompt', 'Programatically added text field'...
    , 'Value', 'Toto'...
    , 'Evaluate', 'on'...
    , 'Tunable', 'off'...
    , 'Enabled', 'on'...
    , 'Visible', 'on'...
    , 'Callback', 'disp( get_param(gcb, ''TextField''))');


wPopup = wMask.addParameter('Name', 'PopupField' ...
    , 'Type', 'popup'...
    , 'Prompt', 'Programatically added popup field'...
    , 'TypeOptions', {'Value1', 'Value2', 'Value3'}...
    , 'Evaluate', 'on'...
    , 'Tunable', 'off'...
    , 'Enabled', 'on'...
    , 'Visible', 'on'...
    , 'Callback', 'disp( get_param(gcb, ''PopupField''))');

wFieldDialog = wMask.getDialogControl('TextField');
wPopupDialog = wMask.getDialogControl('PopupField');

wFieldDialog.moveTo(wTab1);
wPopupDialog.moveTo(wTab2);
```